# android.media.audiofx how to create a 10 band equilizer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp3, audio-processing

I am trying to write my own MP3 player using .NET MAUI.
One of the libraries are based on android media player. As I read in the documentation it has an Equalizer class in the android.media.audiofx package.

I want to create an equalizer for: 32, 64, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000 and 20000Hz, but can't figure it out.

Can anyone show me some sample java code that I can try to translate to c#.
I looked the code [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/android.media.audiofx.Equalizer) but was not a lot of help.

thnx

Answer (score 1):

Android built-in equalizer seems to support only fixed number of bands and fixed frequencies.
For different devices it provides different number of bands.

A way I found to create a X-band EQ is by processing audio stream directly and applying a filter function to the stream raw samples.
But for compressed audio formats it would also require a decoder to get the audio samples.

So one possible chain would be:

- implement an audio engine via JNI, like [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) library.
- implement a filtering algorithm (EQ is basically an audio filter, which can be of low-pass, notch, high-shelf type etc.). The basic idea is to pass audio samples through a formula with specific coefficients.
  Some sources for this:

  - Example implementation: https://github.com/dimtass/DSP-Cpp-filters
  - Check this note from Oboe: https://github.com/google/oboe/wiki/TechNote_Effects
  - Theory on coefficients needed for the filtering: https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html
- setup filters for N bands. If you have a filter class say AudioFilter with properties like gain and frequency, it would serve as 1 band (as a notch/peaking filter type). So to have N bands, you would setup an array of AudioFilter's and adjust separately those parameters.

As I've seen normally, that low-level stuff is in C/C++. But I think it would be possible to convert the code to Java or C# using Android `AudioTrack` for direct audio stream handling.

Check these discussions also:

- https://github.com/google/oboe/issues/296
- https://github.com/google/oboe/issues/1271